# R - cut2 - one bin for zeros and 10 for everything else

Tags: r, data.table, hmisc

I have a data set with a skewed distribution that I would like to divide into bins with equal numbers of observations - except for the skew.

To clarify, I have a large number of zeros, and a relatively small number of > 0 observations.

If I use cut2 to bin the values into 10 bins including the zeros, I get the following.

```
library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)

DT<-data.table(x=rep(0,100), y=rep(0,100))
DT<-rbind(DT, data.table(x=seq(1:100),y=seq(1:100)))
DT
       x   y
  1:   0   0
  2:   0   0
  3:   0   0
  4:   0   0
  5:   0   0
 ---        
196:  96  96
197:  97  97
198:  98  98
199:  99  99
200: 100 100
```

looking just at x

```
data.table(DT[, cut2(x, g=10)])[,.N, by=V1]
         V1   N
1:        0 100
2: [ 1, 21)  20
3: [21, 41)  20
4: [41, 61)  20
5: [61, 81)  20
6: [81,100]  20
```

So the presence of 100 zeros has shifted the bins to the point where the observations above zero are bunched into 5 buckets.

If I specifically filter out the zeros and apply the 10 bins, I get the following as expected...

```
data.table(DT[x>0, cut2(x, g=10)])[,.N, by=V1]
          V1  N
 1: [ 1, 11) 10
 2: [11, 21) 10
 3: [21, 31) 10
 4: [31, 41) 10
 5: [41, 51) 10
 6: [51, 61) 10
 7: [61, 71) 10
 8: [71, 81) 10
 9: [81, 91) 10
10: [91,100] 10
```

What I'd like to do is have 11 buckets - one for the zeros and 10 for the non-zeros.  I can of course apply this with 2 separate operations like so

```
DT[x==0, bin:=cut2(x, g=1)]
Warning message:
In min(diff(x.unique)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

DT[x>0, bin:=cut2(x, g=10)]
DT[, .(min(x), max(x)), by=bin]
         bin V1  V2
 1:        0  0   0
 2: [ 1, 11)  1  10
 3: [11, 21) 11  20
 4: [21, 31) 21  30
 5: [31, 41) 31  40
 6: [41, 51) 41  50
 7: [51, 61) 51  60
 8: [61, 71) 61  70
 9: [71, 81) 71  80
10: [81, 91) 81  90
11: [91,100] 91 100
```

But I then have to repeat those same 2 operations for y.  My actual data table has around 30 columns so I'm wondering if there is:

1. A shortcut that allows me to apply those two operations together for a single column?
2. A further shortcut that allows me to apply those two operations for a list of 30 columns?

The key bit I can see is going to be a struggle is the filter part - the distributions are all skewed toward zero but each column contains differing numbers of observations and will have different bins as such.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

David

p.s. hopefully the layout of the post makes it so you can cut and paste the code - I included the output for clarity but if there are issues with this please let me know.

**EDIT**
After reviewing @Eddi's answer and applying to my data, I can see that there is a problem with the data I've provided vs the data I'm actually running on.

These are the results of running using Eddi's method on my data(names are masked)...

```
> data.table(XXX[, cut2(yyy, m = 
sum(yyy > 0)/10)])[, .N, by = V1]
              V1   N
 1: [   0,    4) 284
 2: [3891,72337] 264
 3: [1212, 3891) 264
 4: [ 519, 1212) 264
 5: [ 208,  519) 263
 6: [  49,  101) 267
 7: [ 101,  208) 263
 8: [  11,   24) 258
 9: [  24,   49) 263
10: [   4,   11) 252
 > XXX[yyy==0, .N,]
 [1] 74
> XXX[yyy>=0, .N,]
[1] 2642
```

I've updated the test data set to reproduce these kind of results as follows - mainly, extending the range of potential values to 70,000 and generating them randomly rather than sequentially.  Also generating 2700 of them rather than the 100 or so I was working with

```
DT<-data.table(x=rep(0,100), y=rep(0,100))
DT<-rbind(DT, data.table(x=runif(2600,1,70000),y=runif(2600,1,70000)))
DT
data.table(DT[, cut2(x, m = sum(x > 0)/10)])[, .N, by = V1]

           V1   N
 1: [    0, 4798) 270
 2: [41289,48407) 270
 3: [11482,18413) 270
 4: [48407,55678) 270
 5: [55678,62157) 270
 6: [33040,41289) 270
 7: [25470,33040) 270
 8: [ 4798,11482) 270
 9: [62157,69983] 270
10: [18413,25470) 270
```

So this has rolled up the bucket for zeros into the rest of the 10 buckets - admittedly this is not impacting the distribution massively, but it's one of the columns where this method appears to break down slightly.

Apologies for the mistake there with the test data, I'd not anticipated this type of impact.

Any thoughts on how to proceed would be welcome...

Cheers

David

Comment: Do the binning of 0 and non-zero separately as you had it, and run in a for loop over columns.

Comment: Hi @Eddi, okay sure - that's ultimately what I've had as my back option but I've learnt a few more tricks with R after seeing your proposal, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

After feedback from Eddi and my own experiments with this, I've decided to use a for loop over a list of columns, specifically binning the zeros first, then binning non-zeros separately.

```
DT<-data.table(x=rep(0,100), y=rep(0,100))
DT<-rbind(DT, data.table(x=runif(100,1,10000),y=runif(100,1,10000)))
DT


cols <- data.table(col_name=c("x","y"))


for(col in 1:nrow(cols)){

    DT[get(cols[col, col_name])==0,(paste(cols[col,col_name],"_bin",sep="")):= cut2(get(cols[col, col_name]),g=1)]
    DT[get(cols[col, col_name])>0,(paste(cols[col, col_name],"_bin",sep="")):= cut2(get(cols[col, col_name]),g=10)]

}  

data.table(DT[, cut2(x, m = sum(x > 0)/10)])[, .N, by = V1]

                   V1   N
 1:              0.00 100
 2: [2540.22,4009.79)  10
 3: [4923.05,5736.81)  10
 4: [4009.79,4923.05)  10
 5: [ 910.57,1563.99)  10
 6: [5736.81,6121.23)  10
 7: [   9.77, 910.57)  10
 8: [9240.77,9957.27]  10
 9: [1563.99,2540.22)  10
10: [6121.23,7759.80)  10
11: [7759.80,9240.77)  10
```